# Template Error with passing member functions that contain a mutex

Tags: c++, templates

I spend an hour wiggling down a large class I needed to pass a member function of to a minimal example. The compiler error given is:

> error C2664: 'B::B(const B &)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty'
> to 'const B &'

Below is a minimal example and the Code compiles fine when using a pointer to the mutex. Can somebody help me understand what went wrong here and why and how I could have gotten hints towards that from the error message in 'tuple'?

Thanks everyone!

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>


class A  {
public:
    std::string Init(std::function<std::string(void)> f) {
        return f();
    }
};

class B {
    std::mutex lock;
    std::string member = "Hello World!";

public:
    std::string foo() {
        return member;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto callback3 = std::bind(&B::foo, B());
    auto instance = A();
    std::cout << instance.Init(callback3) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Eating lunch so fuller answer will follow, `std::mutex` can not be copied - live - follow the clang errors - https://godbolt.org/z/YTEE83h58  `<source>:15:16: note: copy constructor of 'B' is implicitly deleted because field 'lock' has a deleted copy constructor
    std::mutex lock;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `std::mutex` is non-copyable, its copy constructor is deleted. There are no defined semantics for copying a mutex, what does that mean? If a mutex has locked something, does it mean that, somehow, two mutexes managed to lock the same object, the original and the copy, and both must be unlocked. For this reason a `std::mutex` is not copyable.

This makes `B` non-copyable too.

`std::bind` requires a copyable callable object to work with, which results in this compilation error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That makes a lot of sense. I wasn't even aware that std::bind creates copies, I thought I would get a pointer to the method of he original object and not a copy. After reading up on it I have a better picture now.

Comment: You might want to try to pass a pointer to an object, instead of an actual object, to `std::bind`. `B()` is an object, and not a pointer to an object. Whatever gets passed in, gets copied, it's a very simple rule.

Comment: Thank you again. That suggestion together with std::placeholder solved my original callback problem.